# How do I add axis labels to my box plot in python?

Tags: python, plot, boxplot, axis-labels

How do I add labels on the x and y-axis?

This is the python code I have for my plots:

```
fd = pd.read_csv('FD_IWS1.csv')
fd = fd.loc[fd['FD1'] * fd['FD2'] * fd['FD3'] * fd['FD4'] * fd['FD5'] != 0]
boxplot = fd.boxplot(grid=False, rot=45, fontsize=15)
```

What do I need to add to get labels?

Comment: You mean [`boxplot.set_xlabel("X")`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel.html?highlight=set_xlabel#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel("label")`. For instance (I used random values since I do not have your csv):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])
boxplot = df.boxplot(grid=False, rot=45, fontsize=15)

plt.xlabel("Label of X axis")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`bplot=sns.boxplot(data=fd, width=0.5, showfliers=False)`
`bplot.set_title("30 cm Sensor Data", fontsize=16)`
`bplot.set_xlabel("Column", fontsize=14)`
`bplot.set_ylabel("Soil Moisture Level (w/v)", fontsize=14)`
`bplot`